# Substitution problem in an integral

Tags: calculus

Say I have:

$\int_0^\pi\cos^2\theta\sin\theta d\theta$ and I choose to make the substitution $t=\sin\theta$. I then get an integral  $\int_0 ^0 t\sqrt{1-t^2}dt$ and the result is zero. What's the fallacy here? I know I can substitute $\cos\theta$, I was just wondering.

Comment: As $sin(x)$ is not invertible in the interval you can't just put it like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$, $$\cos\theta=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$$ Note the minus sign in front of the square root.

Answer (score 1):

We have the well known result:
$$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$$
From which:
$$\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta$$
Now we have to be careful while taking the square root both sides:
$$\cos\theta=\left|\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta} \right|$$
In the interval:$(0,\pi/2) ,\cos$ is positive. hence we can open the modulus as 
 :$\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ and on the interval $(\pi/2,\pi)$ since $\cos$ is negative, we should open the modulus as: $-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$. We can split the integral as such for easier substitution:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta \ \sin\theta \;\mathrm{d}\theta +\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos^2\theta \ \ \sin\theta\  \mathrm{d}\theta$$
Now once we make the substitution $t=\sin\theta$, our integral changes :
$$\int_0^1t \sqrt{1-t^2}\;\mathrm{d}t+\int_1^0-t\sqrt{1-t^2}\; \mathrm{d}t$$
Simplifying, we reach:
$$2\int_0^1t\sqrt{1-t^2}\; \mathrm{d}t$$